# Bash shells with different environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to somehow enter a different bash shell with some altered environment variables.

For example, if I run script `bfin.sh` and it contains something like

```
export PATH=/home/me/bfin2012:$PATH
```

I want it to create a bash shell with this changed variable. How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

To load environment variables you've put into a file, you can use the `source` command. e.g.

See current path:

```
 > echo $PATH
 /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

File with custom environment settings..

```
 > cat exports
 export PATH="/home/me/bfin2012:$PATH"
 export ...
```

Load custom environment

```
 > source exports
```

Confirm changes.

```
 > env | grep '^PATH'
 PATH=/home/me/bin2012:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already set the variable and exported the set variable.  If you want to enter a **new** bash shell at this point with that variable present, you just run:

```
bash
```

Note that the new shell's startup procedure might end up overwriting your variable, though!  This could happen in `.bashrc`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Either change your script to end with `exec bash`, or run

```
sh -c '. bfin.sh; exec bash'
```

If you want to change the environment of the current shell, run

```
. bfin.sh
```

The [`.` (dot or period)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002e) builtin executes the command from the specified script inside the same shell environment, like a function.

Answer (score 0):

Running the `bfin.sh` script will do little for you.  It would change the value of the `PATH` environment variable and then terminate.  The changed variable is part of the script's environment, so it would be lost when the script ends.

The `bash` shell will automatically source the file mentioned by the `BASH_ENV` variable before running a script, so assuming that your script `myscript` has a `#!`-line referring to the `bash` interpreter, the following would source the `bfin.sh` script and then run your script with the modified environment:

```bsh
BASH_ENV=path/to/bfin.sh ./myscript
```

You may also source the `bfin.sh` script from within your new script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source path/to/bfin.sh

# the rest of the script goes here
```